# Is it possible to get all items in UICollectionView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get all items in a **UICollectionView**.

I coded the below but it's not working the way I want it to. There are 6 items in my CollectionView, but it's displaying just 4 of them. How should  I modify my doe?

```
   for(NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.viewCollection.indexPathsForVisibleItems) {
    //    for(imgCount in self.viewCollection.numberOfSections) {
    //        NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.viewCollection.indexPathsForVisibleItems;
            // Get selected cell
            MYCell* cell = (MYCell*) [_viewCollection cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            if(cell.checked == YES) {
                imgCount = imgCount + 1;

                NSString *imgName = [directoryContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imgName]];
                NSData *imgFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

                if(imgCount == 1) {
                    [IMGDATA_grid appendString:[imgFile base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding76CharacterLineLength]];
                }
                else {
                    [IMGDATA_grid appendString:@","];
                    mTempData = [imgFile base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding76CharacterLineLength];
                    [IMGDATA_grid appendString:mTempData];
                }
            }
     }
```

Comment: You already have all of the data in your collection view's data source. There is no need to iterate through the items.

Comment: Your collection view makes just enough cells to fill the entire screen. When the user scrolls, the collection view takes items which disappeared on one end of the screen and reuses them on the other end of the screen, which is why you use `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(...)` to create cells.

Comment: Your cells are just a view of the data from your model.  Get the data from your model, not from the cells.

Comment: @Paulw11 get the data from model? I don't know what this mean

Comment: @rmaddy Of course all of data in my collection view. But I coded iterate through the items that I have to send the all of data to database server in my collection view

Comment: You have some data model, typically an array, that is providing the data for your cells; access the data from this array, not the cells.  The cells are just a view of this data.  A cell won't exist if that item isn't on screen.  A cell can be discarded at any time.  That is why you need to go to your data.

Comment: @Palle Aha~ I saw the API from Apple developer web site. I will try approved the API my code and confirm the result. Thanks~!

Comment: Your approach is wrong. The displayed cells are just display for portion of data. You have cell.checked but does this state is being saved in your dataSource? If not, then it should be, and you only check whats in the datasource not the cell itself.

Comment: @GeneCode
**cell.checked** is being saved status. So, I touched the cell then changed the checkbox image and reflected to image checked flag variable.

Answer (score 0):

The way CollectionViews (and TableViews etc) work, is that you pass them data from a structure in your code, most likely an NSArray or an NSMutableArray. This is where you keep the data.

**Put data in an array => let your CollectionView access data => display UI**

If you need to access the data elsewhere in your code, refer directly to the data structure, not the UI element itself, particularly because the cells can be removed by the system to save memory.

So say you want to know what the title is of a UICollectionViewCell at row 47, you don't need to go to Cell 47 and ask for its title, but instead refer directly to your data structure, as in:

```
NSString * title = myDataArray[47];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think it s about your collection view algorithm. I mean while using - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method, you should keep data that you use on cell, in an array or model or something like that. Probably 4 items that you can display, are drawn items after viewDidLoad without any scroll action. If you use 3 cells in collectionview with same offset, you can get all items without any problem. Tiny code about what i mean

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"String1",@"String2",@"String3","String4",@"String5",@"String6",nil];

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCollectionViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

[cell setupCellWithString:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;}
```

selecting any item in collection view

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *strInArray = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];}
```

I hope i could understand your problem correctly. Good luck. By the way collectionview.indexPathsForVisibleItems represent items that are drawn and displayed on collectionview.